# php multiple images updating

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating PHP multiple images updating page my script is updating only one image second image updating if i selected all image file only updating first and second image I want to create one by one images updating I have tried to do that's but it's not working

Here is my code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
//$id=$_POST['id'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$desc1=$_POST['desc1'];
$content=$_POST['content'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10); 
$img= $random .$_FILES['image']['name'][0];
$image_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0];
$img1= $random .$_FILES['image']['name'][1];
$image_tmp1= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][1];
if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/$img")){
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp1,"images/$img1");
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE products SET title=?, desc1=?, content=?,  category=?,img=?,img1=?  WHERE id=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $title, $desc1, $content,  $category, $img,$img1, $id);
}else{
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE products SET title=?, desc1=?, content=?,  category=? WHERE id=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $title, $desc1, $content,  $category, $id);
}
if($stmt->execute()){
header('location:edit-source.php');
}else{
echo "Failed to update product<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question again? Should your script upload all the images?

Comment: uploading two images to database and i want to update one by one image this script not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an incorrect logic in place. The logic should be

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
$id=$_POST['id'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$desc1=$_POST['desc1'];
$content=$_POST['content'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10); 
$img= $random .$_FILES['image']['name'][0];
$image_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0];
$img1= $random .$_FILES['image']['name'][1];
$image_tmp1= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][1];
if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/$img")){
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp1,"images/$img1");
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE products SET title=?, desc1=?, content=?,  category=?,img=?,img1=?  WHERE id=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $title, $desc1, $content,  $category, $img,$img1, $id);
} else if (move_uploaded_file($image_tmp1,"images/$img1")) {
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp1,"images/$img");
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE products SET title=?, desc1=?, content=?,  category=? WHERE id=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $title, $desc1, $content,  $category, $id);
}
if($stmt->execute()){
header('location:edit-source.php');
}else{
echo "Failed to update product<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Alternatively, I would recommend wrapping it in a function to make it reusable.

Comment: your scrips is working but when i updated first image auto removing second image

Comment: what id's are you passing when you upload the pics. Do you see pictures uploaded to images folder?

Comment: You have commented this line. //$id=$_POST['id'];
 So same id must have been passing. Uncomment and pass the id correctly.

Comment: problem is when i updated first or second image removing one image

Comment: chandra sekhar thank you very much your script worked finally

Comment: No problem Uththara. Please vote for the answer if you like the response.

Comment: There is an up & down triangle before answer, just hit them and you can vote for it. Up Triangle refers to upvote and down triangle refers to downvote/negative voting.